# How to upload files with NodeJs express-fileuploaf to a Synology NAS shared folder

Tags: node.js, express, file-upload, synology, nas

I would like to upload files using nodejs and express-fileupload to a NAS (Network attached storage) device but I cannot find any documentation for this online. Does anybody know if this is possible?

I cannot use nodejs path to connect to the NAS server.

Comment: 1) You can have your nodejs app directly running on the synology NAS server, [here](https://blog.e-nnov.fr/synology-dsm/node-js/#.Y7AsgHbMJD8). With this approach the files you receive should already be on the NAS server. 2) If your nodejs app is unrelated to the nas server, it seems synology gives some API to communicate with it, [here](https://global.download.synology.com/download/Document/Software/DeveloperGuide/Package/FileStation/All/enu/Synology_File_Station_API_Guide.pdf). The idea, you receive your files on nodejs server and make an http request to the nas server, using the right API

Comment: If you are using DSM OS, you can find some information in this [doc](https://global.download.synology.com/download/Document/Software/DeveloperGuide/Os/DSM/All/enu/DSM_Login_Web_API_Guide_enu.pdf) too,